# log (1-var) operation in C

Tags: c, math

I am trying to code [this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/14/generating-poisson-random-values/) algorithm. I am stuck in the part of `log((1.0-u)/u))/beta`;
As I understand, I can not get the result of this in C, as it will always return me with negative value log (returning imaginary value). 
Tried to print the result of log(1-5) for instance, it gives me with Nan.
How can I get the result of

```
double x = (alpha - log((1.0-u)/u))/beta
```

then?

Would appreciate for any pointers to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: What do you expect? 10 to what power (real number) would equal -4?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: 1.3863 + 3.1416i... (!)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth correct, but remember that log doesn't return a complex number. You'd need a different log function.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that was nice :)

Comment: Just kidding ... you can use the [clog() function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.3.7.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that algorithm, `u` should be uniform random on [0,1], so the quantity `(1-u)/u` is never negative.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass in a value of `u` outside the range `(0,1)` (this is mentioned in one of the comments in that article).  Note that `(` and `)` denote *open* (i.e. exclusive) bounds.

Comment: This is correct; if you read down in the Poisson algorithm you link, it states that the `random()` function listed in the pseudocode returns a number in the range (0,1).  However, if you do need to handle complex numbers, you should look at C99 complex number support.  See this article for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c

Answer (score 1):

As stated you need the range of `u` to be `(0,1)` (if u is 0 or 1 you are in trouble).  You are probably using `rand()` in which case you will want

```
double u = (rand() + 1) / (double)(RAND_MAX + 2);
double x = (alpha - log((1.0-u)/u))/beta
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess u lays between 0 and 1, thus being a normalized positive random.

Answer (score 0):

`log( (1-u)/u ) = log(1-u)-log(u)` and thus `u` needs to be `0<u<1`. The graph looks like this

[image: log(1-u)-log(u)]

In fact you see the anti-symmetry by `u=0.5` you may need to worry only for values between `0` and `0.5`, but not including `0`. So for `u`>0.5 you set `u=1-u` and return `-log(1-u)+log(u)`.