# Error when defining a complex number variable

Tags: c, complex-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to work with complex numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c)

So I have this piece of C code that compiles with errors saying that 'complex' does not name a type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int B=9;
    double theta;

    double complex w;
    float x,y;

    x= 5*cos (theta) - 2;
    y= 5*sin (theta);


    double complex z=x+y*I;
    w=z+(B/z);

    for(theta=0;theta<=360;theta=+30)
    { printf ("%.2f  %.2f  %.2f  %.2f",creal(z), cimag(z),y,creal(w), cimag(w));
        printf ("/n");
    } 

    return 0;

    system ("pause");
}
```

I already include the `<complex.h>` so why is there still an error for the 'complex'. There are also other errors, but let just focus on this one first.

Comment: On my box, the error goes away when I move the declaration of `z` to after the point where `x` and `y` get their values.

Comment: You are not using the header file correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c

Comment: it isn't about the values actually, it is about the 'complex' syntax. It didn't detect the 'complex' eventhough I already #include <complex.h>.

Comment: @AshRj
I did find this answer but sorry to say that I didn't quite understand it. so I need to enable C99 support??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using GCC as your compiler? If yes, you need to enable C99 support by using the `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` compiler flag.

Also, declare variables *before* you use them. Here:

```
double complex z=x+y*I;
```

neither `x` nor `y` have been declared yet. Of course you also need to initialize them. For example:

```
float x = 5 * cos(theta) - 2;
float y = 5 * sin(theta);
double complex z = x + y * I;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I already declare x and y as float actually. I did find that information, but I didn't actually know how to implement it. Can you guide me or give me any link? :)

Comment: @ShahrulNizam How do you run your code ?

Comment: @ShahrulNizam The point is that you're using `x` and `y` before you actually declare them. Read my answer again.

Comment: @NikosC. he is asking how to use the compiler flag

Comment: @ShahrulNizam We need to know your development environment. Are you using Dev-C++? Or aren't you using GCC at all? (For example Visual Studio?)

Comment: @AshRj : I use Dev C++. :)

NikosC. : I've already edited the codes and yup I use Dev C++.

Comment: @ShahrulNizam  In the project options, go to 'parameters', then add '-std=c99' to the 'compiler' textbox (it's been a while since I used it, so first check whether there's a proper checkbox of similar that lets you enable C99 mode.) Btw, if you're using Bloodshed Dev-C++, you should switch to Orwell Dev-C++ (orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com). Bloodshed's version is very old and not maintained anymore.

Comment: thanks a lot @NikosC.
I've already downloaded the orwelldevc++, and I tried to run it now using that. There isn't any error about the 'complex', but it says 
"expected initializer before 'w'" and "'w' is not declared in this scope." Sorry for asking a lot of questions.

Comment: @ShahrulNizam Make sure you set it to C, not C++ (Project -> Project Options -> Compiler -> Code Generation -> Language Standard).

Comment: oho ok. Previously I just create a new source file. It got no errors now but now the output is suddenly in an infinite loop. But it's ok, at least it is running. Later i can give it back to my friend. Thanks a lot guys!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()

{
 int B=9;
 double theta;
 double complex w;
 float x = 5*cos (theta) - 2;
 float y = 5*sin (theta);
 double complex z=x+y*I;

 w=z+(B/z);

 for(theta=0;theta<=360;theta=+30)
  { printf ("%.2f  %.2f  %.2f  %.2f",creal(z), cimag(z),y,creal(w), cimag(w));
   printf ("/n");
  } 

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: thanks man. But I still have problems with the 'complex'. I think its the compiler flag problem. How to enable C99 support??

Comment: Use the -std=c99 compiler flag

Comment: Now it came up with  "expected initializer before 'w'" and "'w' is not declared in this scope.". As far as i can see, w already been decalred.