# complex numbers

Tags: parsing, math, complex-numbers

I am working on a math project.I need a programming language that allows me to evaluate users input.
Like Multiplying 2 complex numbers: I can't use a regular expression since there are many possibilities( I want to include all the steps of calculation.)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The set of complex numbers (with i being an imaginary number. )

Comment: Update your question with example and what you have tried ...

Comment: Whoever retagged this: not `calculus`. Maybe `math`.

Comment: "A regular expression"? What didn't work about it? What language are you using? Did you try a different regular expression? Have you written any other code aside from a regular expression? Having "read the question carefully" it says you "can't use a regular expression," not that you've actually tried it.

Comment: What is the question you are trying to ask?

Comment: think about it like this: (2X +2Y) *(3X+4Y)=....            now here is the complicated step since the user can start multiplying any 2 values together which is always true

Comment: Are you having problems parsing or problems calculating?

Comment: Read the previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Scheme, it's a nice Lisp-like language that has built-in support for complex numbers. Also, since in Scheme data is code, it is really easy to turn user input into executable code.

[Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/) is a popular variant.

Other popular languages with built-in complex number support are:

- R: use `i` as suffix for imaginary numbers. `(1+2i)^2` returns `-3+4j`.
- Python: use `j` as a suffix for imaginary numbers. `(1+2j)**2` returns `(-3+4j)`.
- Ruby: use the [`Complex`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Complex.html) class.
- C:  include `complex.h` and use `I` as the imaginary unit. See also [How to work with complex numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c)