# C: declare type in <complex.h>

Tags: c, gcc, complextype

I have a code that uses complex number.

When I declare the variable "x", which is a complex number with size of double, should I declare it as:

```
complex double x;
```

or

```
double complex x;
```

?
Does it make any difference? Does anyone have experience on compilers
not understanding either of them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c

Comment: It probably makes no difference because all "typey words" at the beginning of a declaration can be reordered: `static const unsigned long int` is the same as `int unsigned static long const`, so I'd assume `_Complex` (and its macro alias `complex`) follow the same rule.

Comment: I don't know why this reasonable question is being downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard says, in 6.7.2 Type Specifiers

> Each list of type specifiers shall be one of the following sets [...] the type specifiers may occur in any order
>
> - ...
> - `float _Complex`
> - `double _Complex`
> - `long double _Complex`

Although the standard consistently puts `_Complex` (and therefore `complex`) after double, float, and long double, it permits any order

```
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    long double complex d1;
    double long complex d2;
    complex long double d3;
    complex double long d4;
    double complex long d5;
    long complex double d6;
}
```

demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cbc966b0c1b096e

Comment: That make sense so much. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference for this question, but you're quoting the C99 standard rather than the current C11 standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, indeed, c11's wording is better, thank you for spotting.

Answer (score 2):

This is specified in the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (N1570 draft), section 6.7.2.

A *type-specifier* is any of several keywords and other constructs, including **`float`**, **`long`**, **`double`**, and **`_Complex`**.  Paragraph 2 says (emphasis added)

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration
>   specifiers in each declaration, and in the specifier-qualifier list in
>   each struct declaration and type name. Each list of type specifiers
>   shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when
>   there is more than one multiset per item); **the type specifiers may
>   occur in any order**, possibly intermixed with the other declaration
>   specifiers.

And in paragraph 5:

> Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that [*irrelevant exception omitted*].

The listed multisets include:

- **`float _Complex`**
- **`double _Complex`**
- **`long double _Complex`**

Which means that, for example, `long double _Complex` and `_Complex double long` are both equally valid, and have the same meaning.

(The standard uses the slightly obscure term "multiset" because the number of times a type specifier occurs can be meaningful. If not for `long long`, it would have used the word "set".)

And the `<complex.h>` standard header defines the macro `complex`, which expands to the keyword `_Complex`.

I know of no C compiler that supports `_Complex` but doesn't permit type specifiers to be in any order. If you find one, submit a bug report.

Having said that, there's no point in arbitrarily reordering type specifiers. `double complex` is the most idiomatic form (which of course requires `#include <complex.h>`). Though the syntax doesn't treat them that way, you can think of `double` as an adjective and `complex` as a noun; `double complex` is a *complex* type, not a *double* type.