# Why are `ccos`, `csqrt`, `cpow` not recognised?

Tags: c++, header-files, complex-numbers

Why am I getting these errors? (I have a `clang/g++` compiler.)

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ccos'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'csqrt'; did you mean 'sqrt'?
error: use of undeclared identifier 'cpow'; did you mean 'pow'?
```

and so forth. I have declared my function as:

```
#include <complex>

double ghmc1AccNormalised( double ph, double r, double t, double th){

    complex<double> numerator;
    complex<double> denominator;
    double E = exp(1);


    numerator=-(cpow(E,t*((-2*r + r*ccos(th) + r* // ... etc
        // what follows is 24MB of a horrible polynomial from Mathematica
        ...
    denominator = cpow(2,0.3333333333333333) //... etc

return creal(numerator/denominator);
}
```

I am trying to ensure that I am handling the imaginary variables correctly.
I have spent a long time looking at various posts but I have the following issues:

- The values are coming out as `inf` and `nan` when they shouldn't
- I suspected that this was due to complex numbers not being handled properly
- [This highly rated post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860772/4013571) notes that `ccos`, `csqrt` etc. should be used for complex arguments
- I have tried various namespaces in addition to the above:

  - `using complex;`
  - `using std::complex;`
  - I tried also prepending `std::complex` and `complex::` to each function

*Disclaimer* This is my first `c/c++` function so please ignore trivial issues unless directly related to the question

Comment: `std::complex` is a class, not a namespace. `cpow` etc. You can use a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) to see that the C++ functions do not have the leading c and are in `std`.

Comment: As per the OP, I have also tried not including that line. I'll edit the post as it's going to distract form the issue

Comment: I was referring to *I tried also prepending std::complex and complex:: to each function*

Comment: That "highly rated post" is about a different language (C, not C++).

Comment: Also, that denominator could be written as just `std::cbrt(2)`. That's the `c` of "cubic root", not complex.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but to save any else time on improvements relating to the main function body: The numerator and denominator are part of 24 million scrambled polynomials so I've no intention of messing with the contents and the function is not limiting performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using functions from the C header `complex.h`, which you are not including. But the [C++ header `complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex) provides overloads for [`cos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/cos), [`sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sin), [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow), etc<sup>*</sup>. You should use these instead of their C counterparts.

```
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> c{1, 2};
    auto c2 = pow(c, 2);
    auto cc = sqrt(c2);
}
```

---

<sup>* Note that these are in the `std` namespace, but so is `std::complex`, so argument dependent lookup (ADL) allows you to invoke them without the namespace.</sup>

Comment: how can I use these? I already came across this website and assumed that  `<complex>` needed an `#include <complex>` is no header required?

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Just use them.

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Instead of `ccos()`, use `cos()`, etc.

Comment: Is it literally a case of deleting `#include <complex>` and just using `cos()`, `sin()` etc?

Comment: No. The `complex` header includes `std::complex` and the overloads for `cos`, `sin`, etc. Just replace `ccos` with `cos` and so on

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane I added links to some documentation with examples.

Comment: AH right so they overload the operations and extend the existing `cos()` `sin()` etc. into complex operations

Comment: And there's the real part callable object-style: `(numerator/denominator).real()`