# Why can the same code be compiled successfully through gcc while not g++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

The following `test.c` can be compiled successfully by using `gcc` compiler:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <complex.h>

int main(void) {
    double complex a = 0;
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o test1 test.c
$
```

While after changing the name to `test.cpp`, and compile it with `g++` compiler, there is an error:

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <complex.h>

int main(void) {
    double complex a = 0;
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -o test2 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:20: error: expected initializer before ‘a’
     double complex a = 0;
                    ^
```

Why can the same code be compiled successfully through `gcc` while not `g++`?

P.S. My compiler versions:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.1 20160830 (GCC)
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.1 20160830 (GCC)
```

Comment: In C "Complex types are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.) ", perhaps the C++ compiler lacks `complex` support or some compile option needed?

Comment: @perreal: Still the same error.

Comment: C++ has a complex type built in to the std class.  The g++ compiler thinks you are using that one, which you would declare like this: `std::complex<float> my_complex(1,1);`

Comment: _The headers <complex.h>, <ccomplex>, <tgmath.h>, and <ctgmath> do not contain any content from the C standard library and instead merely include other headers from the C++ standard library. The use of all these headers is deprecated in C++._

Comment: @NanXiao The way you declared complex type is incorrect..

Comment: This is another example for C is not a subset of C++. Don't expect anything works with C will work with C++

Comment: Because C is not a subset if C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic reason is that C and C++ support complex numbers in fundamentally different ways, which are code incompatible.   So C code which uses complex variables, and operations on them, cannot be used in any version of C++, and vice versa.

In C++ (all versions) complex arithmetic is supported by a templated class named `complex`, which is defined in header `<complex>`, and is in namespace `std`.   Since it is a C++ (templated) class in `namespace std`, which C does not support at all, this type and the C++ header `<complex>` cannot be used in C.

Standard C, before 1999, did not support complex variables or arithmetic.  In C (since 1999), complex arithmetic is supported using a `_Complex` keyword, and a convenience macro `complex` (`#define`d in `<complex.h>`) which uses it.   C++ does not support the `_Complex` keyword or `<complex.h>`.

Comment: Note that g++ does support `_Complex` for compatibility with C, if you rename `complex` to `_Complex` the example compiles. However, the macro `complex` is disabled because it would break valid C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <complex>

int main(void) {
    std::complex<double> a = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

In C++, complex is a template, here is the reference [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: I guess it should be `std::complex`?

Answer (score 1):

For **C++** Complex type : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

For **C** Complex type: [How to work with complex numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c)

The Complex.h works differently in C and C++