# How are complex numbers(and the imaginary number i) represented in Native C as opposed to C++?

Tags: c++, c, complex-numbers, procedural-programming

In particular, the  class doesn't have much in the way of data structure definitions of complex numbers. You could represent it by:

```
struct complex{
  double real;
  double imaginary;

};
```

But the imaginary number i = sqrt(-1) cannot be reduced to a primitive type since primitive numerical types are necessarily real numbers. So it would have to be defined implicitly by means of the complex product. This is very easy to do in an object oriented language that allows operator overloading but how is it done with a procedural language like C?

Comment: You would use function calls for each of the operations.

Comment: `complex.h`...you can use that also? (built in functionality for complexy numbers)Or else...you need to create method for handling each of the operation

Comment: "*primitive numerical types are necessarily real numbers*" - no, C has built in complex numbers.

Comment: There is support for a complex type. Also, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860772/1983495).

Comment: Note that floating-point types are **not** real numbers. Keeping that in mind will save you a great deal of grief in the future.

Comment: @PeteBecker real floating point types are of course real numbers save for infinities and nans. But those numbers are also always rational numbers with divisor being a power of two...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala — every rational number is a real number, but rational numbers do not have all of the properties of real numbers, so it not correct to say that rational numbers are real numbers. Equating the two leads to fundamental misunderstandings of how floating-point math works.

Comment: @melpomene but how does one represent the imaginary number i in binary? The issue is that the exponentiation of i is periodic(modulo 4).

Comment: @SavedbyZer0 As far as I know the standard representation of complex numbers is a pair of real numbers, so i would be (0, 1).

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
_Complex double x = _Complex_I;
```

You can do the usual arithmetic operations on complex numbers. The header `#include <complex.h>` declares complex versions of the usual math functions (trig, roots etc.)

Comment: The standard says you write `double _Complex` — and does not mention `_Complex double`.  Can you identify the compiler that allows what you wrote?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't wish to research any specific compiler behaviour . The standard permits `_Complex double` and `double _Complex`; any compiler that rejects one of those would be bugged.

Comment: I presume the examples in the Standard use a particular order for the sake of consistency. `long unsigned int` is never mentioned by the standard either, but it is allowed. C11 6.7.2/2 specifically says that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: OK.  You could quote §6.7.2 ¶2: _At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,
and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of
type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there
is more than one multiset per item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
intermixed with the other declaration specifiers._   …As you just noted in your comment...    One of the lists referred to is `double _Complex`.  I'd not seen things written in the reverse order.

Comment: OK. I just meant to give an example, not provide a full specification :) OP seemed to be unaware of `_Complex` entirely.

Comment: The header `<complex.h>` also has a macro `I`, that is the one that is supposed as a user interface for either `_Complex_I` or `_Imaginary_I`.

Answer (score 2):

Section [§6.2.5 **Types**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5) of the [C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) says, in part:

> ¶10 There are three *real floating types*, designated as `float`, `double`, and `long double`.<sup>42)</sup> The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the
>   type `double`; the set of values of the type `double` is a subset of the set of values of the
>   type `long double`.
>
> ¶11 There are three *complex types*, designated as `float _Complex`, `double _Complex`, and `long double _Complex`.<sup>43)</sup> (Complex types are a conditional
>   feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.) The real floating and
>   complex types are collectively called the *floating types*.
>
> ¶12 For each floating type there is a *corresponding real type*, which is always a real floating
>   type. For real floating types, it is the same type. For complex types, it is the type given
>   by deleting the keyword `_Complex` from the type name.
>
> ¶13 Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array
>   type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is
>   equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex
>   number.
>
> <sup>42)</sup> See ‘‘future language directions’’ (6.11.1).
>   <sup>43)</sup> A specification for imaginary types is in annex G.
>
> #### [6.11.1 Floating types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.1)
>
> ¶1 Future standardization may include additional floating-point types, including those with
>   greater range, precision, or both than `long double`.

There's also the library specification [§7.3 Complex arithmetic `<complex.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.3):

> #### 7.3.1 Introduction
>
> ¶1 The header `<complex.h>` defines macros and declares functions that support complex
>   arithmetic.<sup>192)</sup>
>
> ¶2 Implementations that define the macro `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` need not provide
>   this header nor support any of its facilities.
>
> ¶3 Each synopsis specifies a family of functions consisting of a principal function with one
>   or more `double complex` parameters and a `double complex` or `double` return
>   value; and other functions with the same name but with `f` and `l` suffixes which are
>   corresponding functions with `float` and `long double` parameters and return values.
>
> 4 The macro
>
> ```
> complex
> ```
>
> expands to `_Complex`; the macro
>
> ```
> _Complex_I
> ```
>
> expands to a constant expression of type `const float _Complex`, with the value of
>   the imaginary unit.<sup>193)</sup>
>
> ¶5 The macros
>
> ```
> imaginary
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> _Imaginary_I
> ```
>
> are defined if and only if the implementation supports imaginary types;<sup>194)</sup> if defined,
>   they expand to `_Imaginary` and a constant expression of type `const float
>   _Imaginary` with the value of the imaginary unit.
>
> ¶6 The macro
>
> ```
> I
> ```
>
> expands to either `_Imaginary_I` or `_Complex_I`. If `_Imaginary_I` is not defined, `I` shall expand to `_Complex_I`.
>
> ¶7 Notwithstanding the provisions of 7.1.3, a program may undefine and perhaps then
>   redefine the macros `complex`, `imaginary`, and `I`.
>
> <sup>192)</sup> See ‘‘future library directions’’ (7.31.1).
>   <sup>193)</sup> The imaginary unit is a number *i* such that *i<sup>2</sup> = −1*.
>   <sup>194)</sup> A specification for imaginary types is in informative annex G.

And there's a 14-page [Annex G](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#G), which starts:

> #### Annex G
>
> (normative)
>
> #### IEC 60559-compatible complex arithmetic
>
> #### G.1 Introduction
>
> ¶1 This annex supplements annex F to specify complex arithmetic for compatibility with
>   IEC 60559 real floating-point arithmetic. An implementation that defines
>   `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` shall conform to the specifications in this annex.<sup>375)</sup>
>
> <sup>375)</sup> Implementations that do not define `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` are not required to conform to these specifications.
>
> #### G.2 Types
>
> ¶1 There is a new keyword _Imaginary, which is used to specify imaginary types. It is
>   used as a type specifier within declaration specifiers in the same way as _Complex is
>   (thus, _Imaginary float is a valid type name).
>
> ¶2 There are three imaginary types, designated as float _Imaginary, double
>   _Imaginary, and long double _Imaginary. The imaginary types (along with
>   the real floating and complex types) are floating types.
>
> ¶3 For imaginary types, the corresponding real type is given by deleting the keyword
>   _Imaginary from the type name.
>
> ¶4 Each imaginary type has the same representation and alignment requirements as the
>   corresponding real type. The value of an object of imaginary type is the value of the real
>   representation times the imaginary unit.
>
> ¶5 The imaginary type domain comprises the imaginary types.

---

It's curious that footnote 194 designates Annex G as 'informative' but the Annex identifies itself as 'normative'.  Footnote 43 does mention 'normative' or 'informative'.

---

Section 6.2.5 ¶13 of the C standard is quite clear about how a complex variable shall be represented.